# CoreData relationships loops?

Tags: swift, core-data, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities `Buildings` and `GroupOfBuildings`:

`Building1` has: `GroupOfBuildings1`
`Building2` has: `GroupOfBuildings1`

`GroupOfBuildings1` has: `Building1`, `Building2` and `Building3`

Relationships:

```
Building <<----> GroupOfBuildings
Building <<--->> GroupOfBuildings
Building <---->> GroupOfBuildings
```

[image: relationships]

---

### Question:

`GroupOfBuildings` has a group of `Buildings` which can be used in `Buildings` and also contains a `mainBuildings` reference to `Buildings`. On top of it, `Buildings` needs a reference to `GroupOfBuildings`. Is this the right way of setting up the relationships or is there another way of doing this? It seems setting multiple (looping) relationships isn't how I should do things. Any advice?

---

Sample code:

```
let buildingDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Buildings", in: context)!
let building1 = Buildings(entity: buildingDescription, insertInto: context)
let building2 = Buildings(entity: buildingDescription, insertInto: context)
let building3 = Buildings(entity: buildingDescription, insertInto: context)

let groupOfBuildingDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "GroupOfBuildings", in: context)!
let groupOfBuildings1 = GroupOfBuildings(entity: groupOfBuildingDescription, insertInto: context)

groupOfBuildings1.mainBuilding = building1
groupOfBuildings1.groupOfBuildings = Set([building2, building3])

building1.groupOfBuildings = groupOfBuildings1
building2.groupOfBuildings = groupOfBuildings1
```

---

### Note:

I have another question which uses the same data, but questions are different.

Comment: I agree with @trapper in his answer below both that you can do it and about the naming but it’s not just the naming that’s confusing, the design also confuses me and perhaps even yourself. It is not possible to give you any real advice on how to improve the design since it is hard to understand what a group is and what item refers to in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to follow due to the bad naming. Call things what they are and don't pluralise the object names. `Buildings` should be called `Building`, `GroupOfBuildings` probably `BuildingGroup`, no idea what 'items' refers to...

That said there is no problem with setting up multiple relationships between the same objects. You can have `buildingGroup.mainBuilding`, `buildingGroup.otherBuildings`, `buildingGroup.extraBuildings` all fine, just name them properly so they make sense.